# Disconnect laptop battery from terminal

Tags: laptop, battery

Is it possible to disconnect the battery from the kernel using a software solution, while connected to AC power? In case it is, how?

I would have to open the laptop to physically disconnect it.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...

Comment: I want to take the battery out while its connected to AC, so I can preserve it better. I cant do that as its built in without the option to remove the battery. So my question is is there is any way to change power source to the plugged charger so the battery would remain unused. Thank you!

Comment: I would have thought that depended entirely on hardware configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The battery is hardware, and connected to the motherboard. Software can't simply stop the flow of current from the battery to the mainboard.

Some Lenovo Thinkpads can limit battery charge level within a certain range. TLP can be used to adjust that range.
However, you have an Ideapad, which is a consumer device.

You would have to implement some kind of wireless switch to disconnect the battery.

Edit: Your battery will stop charging when it tops off. If you want to prevent overcharging simply unplug when it hits, say, 80%, and charge when it hits 20%. You can even just keep the battery out when using it at home if you're that paranoid about draining your battery.

If and when your battery does lose much of its charge, buy a replacement, open up the computer, and replace it. It'll teach you some hardware repair skills.